# Webflux data check with mongo reactive spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I try to learn Webflux, but im facing problem when i want to validate list id of employee before save the data.
And my qestion
How to catch error, when employeId is doesn't exist and show the error to client?

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/{tenantId}/outlet")
public Mono<OutletEntity> createNewOutlet(@PathVariable String tenantId, @RequestBody OutletEntity outletEntity) {
    return Mono.just(outletEntity).map(outletEntity1 -> {
        outletEntity.getEmployees().forEach(s -> {
            this.employeeService.getRepository().existsById(s).subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                System.out.println(aBoolean);
                if (!aBoolean) {
                    /**
                     * variable s is employeId
                     * i want to validate every single  employee id before save new outlet
                     */
                    throw new ApiExceptionUtils("tenant not found", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(),
                            StatusCodeUtils.TENANT_NOT_FOUND);
                }
            });
        });
        return outletEntity1;
    }).flatMap(outletEntity1 -> {
        outletEntity.setTenantId(tenantId);
        return  this.outletRepository.save(outletEntity);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way run your validation in the same chain without additional subscriber

```
return Flux.fromIterable(outletEntity.getEmployees()) (1)
        .flatMap(this.employeeService.getRepository()::existsById)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .map(aBoolean -> {
            if (!aBoolean) { (2)
                throw new ApiExceptionUtils("tenant not found", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value(),
                    StatusCodeUtils.TENANT_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            else {
                return aBoolean;
            }
        })
        .then(Mono.just(outletEntity)) (3)
        .flatMap(outletEntity1 -> {
            outletEntity.setTenantId(tenantId);
            return  this.outletRepository.save(outletEntity);
        });
```

1) Create *Flux* from employees collection and iterate via reactor streams with a validation;

2) Check if your type false and throw exception, it stops this chain;

3) If everything ran smoothly [then()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) switch to *Mono* with the outletEntity, saves it and returns;

About error handling.
If you don't handle errors, WebFlux resolve it in *DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler*.

You can add your own error handling like in Web MVC or add you custom exception handler in the *WebFlux Config*.

More details you can read here: [web-reactive](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html)

Comment: when using this code the exception its called and print in the terminal, but the client didnt know that employeeId is doenst exist and the request successfully storing into db. My goal is when the employeId is not exist throw exception and fail to save and send error response.

Comment: I see you point, I corrected my answer according to your question.

Comment: Wow, its worked. I have more question what if, we need more validation that combine mono and flux. example in outletEntity there is 2 flux that must be validate.

Comment: Feel free to ask)